# Pasar Prop en ruta en vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Quiero enviar una prop en una ruta para utilizarla en una nueva vista y no doy con el fallo, he revisado la documentación y he adaptado el código a las especificaciones, para tal cometido tengo el siguiente código:

Router.js:

```
{
    path: "deploy/:id",
    name:'deploy_individual',
    component: () =>
        import ( /* webpackChunkName: "deploy" */ "./views/Deploy.vue"),
    props:true,
},
```

Vista principal que llama a la ruta a la que quiero pasar el prop:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-row>
      <b-colxx xxs="12">
        <button @click="changeRoute('deploy_individual',deploy.name)">GO!</button>
      </b-colxx>
    </b-row>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
 
  data() {
    return {
     
    };
  },

  
  methods: {
    changeRoute(deploy,id) {
     
      this.$router.push({
        name: deploy,
        props: true,
        params: { id: id, type_app: "test title" },
      });
    },
   
  },
};
</script>
```

Y finalmente la vista donde quiero recibir la prop:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="status_id == 0">
    <div>
      <b-row>
        <b-colxx sm="12" md="10" class="mb-4">
         //testeo la prop {{ type_app }}
          
        </b-colxx>
      </b-row>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "Deploy",
  
  props: {
    type_app: {
      type: String,
      default:'---',
       required: true
    },

  },
};
</script>
```

El problema es que no logro obtener la prop en la nueva vista, Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la vista principal, el segundo parámetro que pasas a `changeRoute()`, `deploy` no está definido, por lo tanto no puede leer `deploy.name`. En caso de ser este el error, trabaja con el inspector de tu navegador para obtener los errores de ejecución. El resto del código lo he probado y funciona. Saludos